# How to compare if a slope changes according to a factor? - Linear mixed effects model

Tags: mixed-model

I am trying to find the best way to test if a slope of a linear relationship ($y \sim x$) changes according to a factor.

Using R, my data looks like this 
(at the end of this entry you have a complete data.frame of the data used in this post),

```
head(Data)
           y           x factor1 factor2
1  -2.338990 -0.91800895     one       A
2  -3.050105 -0.52883632     one       A
3  -2.212088 -0.33776995     one       A
4  -3.179068 -0.12151261     one       A
5  -2.992224 -0.40163602     one       A
```

with **factor1** being "one", "two" or "three", and **factor2** being "A" or "B".

Plotting the data, it can be seen that the relationship $y \sim x$ change according **factor1**,

[image]

so I'm using the next linear mixed effects model to analyze the $y \sim x$ relationship:

```
lmc <- lmeControl(niterEM = 5200, msMaxIter = 5200)

model <- lme(y ~ x, random = ~ x | factor1,
             data=Data, method="ML", control = lmc)
```

I'm trying to test if the slope of the previous model changes according to **factor2**. To do that, I split the original data.frame according to **factor2** and I have adjusted the same model for each data set:

```
Data.A <- subset(Data, factor2=="A")
Data.B <- subset(Data, factor2=="B")

model.A <- lme(y ~ x, random = ~ x | factor1,
               data=Data.A, method="ML", control = lmc)

model.B <- lme(y ~ x, random = ~ x | factor1,
               data=Data.B, method="ML", control = lmc)
```

---

**Regarding my question**, I'm not sure which is the best way to compare if the slopes of **model.A** and **model.B** are different. I'm not even sure if this is the best way to make such a comparison. Finally, should I fit models **model.A** and **model.B** using ML or REML?

Thanks in advance.

Here you have the data used above

```
           y           x factor1 factor2
1  -2.338990 -0.91800895     one       A
2  -3.050105 -0.52883632     one       A
3  -2.212088 -0.33776995     one       A
4  -3.179068 -0.12151261     one       A
5  -2.992224 -0.40163602     one       A
6  -1.880848 -0.10092233     one       A
7  -2.737251 -0.11397370     one       A
8  -3.072523 -0.32486116     one       A
9  -2.409865 -0.39230649     one       A
10 -3.442688 -0.68484419     one       A
11 -3.338624 -0.58370030     one       B
12 -3.034527 -1.15890168     one       B
13 -3.365919 -1.13107303     one       B
14 -3.788340 -0.87884973     one       B
15 -3.195439 -0.43406912     one       B
16 -2.985603 -0.80955617     one       B
17 -4.110600 -1.27469536     one       B
18 -3.767803 -0.69183510     one       B
19 -3.969556 -1.04368813     one       B
20 -4.584916 -1.42769288     one       B
21 -3.560453 -1.11932899     two       A
22 -2.611846 -0.34761278     two       A
23 -2.868966 -0.28752233     two       A
24 -3.227665 -0.62711782     two       A
25 -3.915335 -0.56974521     two       A
26 -2.713189 -0.07680714     two       A
27 -4.301062 -1.33046210     two       A
28 -3.080208  0.30942696     two       A
29 -2.761659 -0.09386136     two       A
30 -3.950102 -1.16977572     two       A
31 -3.328332 -0.37093220     two       B
32 -4.491525 -1.28221883     two       B
33 -2.201023 -0.38305905     two       B
34 -3.655213 -0.71137897     two       B
35 -3.084210 -0.43002094     two       B
36 -2.612309  0.04021198     two       B
37 -2.984951 -0.19519072     two       B
38 -3.209870  0.46434417     two       B
39 -4.683885 -2.09611486     two       B
40 -3.103335 -0.50802485     two       B
41 -1.614393 -1.21853767   three       A
42 -2.205823 -1.81694026   three       A
43 -3.294970 -2.52949634   three       A
44 -2.355456 -2.05624649   three       A
45 -2.294678 -1.84959296   three       A
46 -2.326892 -1.81139250   three       A
47 -1.823882 -1.30214244   three       A
48 -2.201914 -1.65529396   three       A
49 -2.968895 -2.09926278   three       A
50 -3.373972 -2.98859374   three       A
51 -1.635867 -0.84790502   three       B
52 -2.291281 -1.67404858   three       B
53 -2.508730 -1.94087563   three       B
54 -2.135895 -1.33531226   three       B
55 -2.614374 -1.94309237   three       B
56 -2.482091 -1.89546774   three       B
57 -2.433470 -1.53194048   three       B
58 -2.176858 -1.72250368   three       B
59 -2.515600 -1.98610068   three       B
60 -2.960277 -2.30500162   three       B
```

---

## EDIT

As [mkt](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/340551/how-to-compare-if-a-slope-changes-according-to-a-factor-linear-mixed-effects#comment643339_340551) said, I included an interaction term in the model as,

```
model <- lme(y ~ x + x:factor2 ...
```

Should this new term be included in random effects as:

```
model <- lme(y ~ x + x:factor2, random = ~ x + x:factor2 | factor1,
             data=Data, method="ML")
```

or I must leave the structure as follows:

```
model <- lme(y ~ x + x:factor2, random = ~ x | factor1,
             data=Data, method="ML")
```

Regards!

## EDIT 2 - SOLVED.

Finally, as **factor2** is not nested in **factor1**, I used a crossed random effect to analyze the influence of **factor2** on the slope.

I compared with an anova() the following models:

```
model1 <- lmer(y ~ x + 
              (x | factor1),
               data=Data, REML = F)

model2 <- lmer(y ~ x + 
              (x | factor1) +
              (-1 + x | factor2),
               data=Data, REML = F)

anova(model1, model2)
```

---

For the [amoeva](https://stats.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/643988?noredirect=1) comment, *Data* shared in this post is only a sample of the complete database. In the original database, **factor1** has 12 levels, **factor1.1** has 24 levels (with factor1/factor1.1) and **factor2** has 2 levels non-nested in factor1/factor1.1.

```
Data       
¦--factor1-01  
¦   ¦--factor1.1-01
¦   ¦   °--factor2-01 
¦   °--factor1.1-02
¦       °--factor2-02  
¦--factor1-02  
¦   ¦--factor1.1-03
¦   ¦   °--factor2-01 
¦   °--factor1.1-04
¦       °--factor2-02  
¦--factor1-03  
¦   ¦--factor1.1-05
¦   ¦   °--factor2-01 
¦   °--factor1.1-06
¦       °--factor2-02  
¦
...
```

what I really use is a comparison like the following:

```
model1 <- lmer(y ~ x +
                  (x | factor1) +
                  (x | factor1:factor1.1),
                  data = Data, REML = F)
```

vs

```
model2 <- lmer(y ~ x +
                  (x | factor1) +
                  (x | factor1:factor1.1) +
             (-1 + x | factor2),
                  data = Data, REML = F)
```

Comment: Instead of writing separate models for the data subsets, write a single model but include 'factor2' in it. Look at posts containing both `mixed-model` and `interaction` tags: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mixed-model+interaction

Comment: Nicso,i see that you use ANOVA test but are you sure that your data is normally distributed? Have you try a Wald Test?

Comment: You should not use a mixed model if you have only 2 and 3 levels per factor. It is too few. Why don't you use a usual regression (`lm`) with `y ~ x*factor1*factor2`?

Comment: Luigi, Data shared in this post is only a sample of the complete database.
$y$ and $x$ are normally distributed.

Comment: It would be better to post the solution as an answer (that is, in the answer box) than as part of the question. Please do so!